# List of Items always null MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am stuck in this problem and i cannot solve it.

This is my `ViewModel`

```
public class AddOrderReceive
{
  public string item_name { get; set; }
  public DateTime? date_received { get; set; }
  public decimal? quantity_received { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  public decimal? item_rate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `View`

```
    @model List<newtest.Models.AddOrderReceive>

    @if(Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
          <tr>
              @if(Model[i].quantity_remaining == 0)
              {
                <td colspan="6" class="text-center">Already Sent</td>
              }
              else
              {
                @Html.HiddenFor(r => Model[i].item_id)
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model[i].IsSelected)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => Model[i].item_rate)</td>
              }
           </tr>
        }
  }
```

And finally, This is my `Controller`:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddRAR(int? my_id)
    {
      try
      {
        var get_items = (from or in db.orders
                         where or.id == my_id
                         select new AddOrderReceive()
                         {
                           item_name = or.item_name,
                           quantity_received = or.quantity_receive,
                           date_received = or.date_receive,
                           order_receive_id = or.order_receive_id 
                         }).ToList();

foreach(var t in get_items)
 {
   var get_remain = (from ra in db.order_detail
                     where ra.contract_id == t.ca_id && ra.order_receive_id == t.order_receive_id 
                     select new
                     {
                       consump_quantity = ra.consump_quantity
                     });
                    t.quantity_remaining = t.quantity_received - get_remain.Sum(r => r.consump_quantity) ?? t.quantity_received;

                }
        return View(get_items);


    }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {

     }


    }  


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddReceivng(List<AddOrderReceive> rc_form)
{
       //Some Logic
}
```

The problem is that whenever I post the form, it is always `null`. But when I remove this block:

```
@if(Model[i].quantity_remaining == 0)
{
    <td colspan="6" class="text-center">Already Sent</td>
}
```

It starts working. I don't know what's the problem. I've searched everywhere but still can't figure out the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@if(Model[i].quantity_remaining == 0)` block of code, if its executed in the first iteration, means that your collection indexers would not be zero based. The `DefaultModelBinder` requires that collection indexers start at zero and be consecutive.

You can override this behavior by including a hidden input for the indexer. Note also that an `<input>` is not a valid child of a `<tr>`, and should be inside a `<td>` element.

```
for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @if(Model[i].quantity_remaining == 0)
    {
        <td colspan="6" class="text-center">Already Sent</td>
    }
    else
    {
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="Index" value="@i" /> // Add this
            @Html.HiddenFor(r => r[i].item_id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r[i].IsSelected)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => r[i].item_rate)</td>
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's true, but i don't know if its executed at the first iteration or last. But i have added the `input` in my form, as above, but still the index starts at `[3]` because first 3 iterations are not executed.

Comment: Adding the hidden input for the indexer solves the issue. And it the collection is `null` in the POST method it means that the first one does enter the `if` block. If say the first two entered the `else` block and the third one entered he `if` block, then your collection would contain the first two items.

Comment: If on the other hand you want to receive all items in the collection, then you would need to add at least an input for one of the properties (say `item_id`) and then your view model might need an additional (`bool`) property to indicate its not being edited

Comment: Thank you so much again. And i have accepted it. I was just testing it one more time, in case i needed your help again :) . Thanks again.